# How did Vader know the Tantive IV went to Tatooine at the end of Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, a-new-hope, rogue-one

At the end of *[Rogue One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_One)*, Darth Vader [watches the Tantive IV escape by jumping into hyperspace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149080/why-was-darth-vaders-cape-fluttering-at-the-end-of-rogue-one?s=24%7C1.5757). At the start of *[A New Hope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(film))*, Darth Vader's ship is firing lasers on the *Tantive IV*. So he must have been able to track it somehow to Tatooine.

In other scenes from Star Wars, Vader and the Imperial Fleet are **not** able to track a ship when it jumps. For example, when the Millennium Falcon jumps into hyperspace after leaving Cloud City at the end of *[The Empire Strikes Back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back)*. Or when the Millennium Falcon jumps into hyperspace to escape the Death Star in *A New Hope*.

To quote General Motti from *A New Hope*, his sorcerer's ways obviously don't give him clairvoyance enough to track down the stolen data tapes.

**So did he have extra information that allowed him to find the *Tantive IV*?** Just as [he had extra information that allowed him to find the rebel base on Hoth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129118/how-did-darth-vader-know-the-rebel-base-was-on-hoth) in *The Empire Strikes Back*.

Is there anything in the novelizations or extended universe that mentions somebody told him the *Tantive IV* was at Tatooine?

Edit to add: [This other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149815/can-ships-be-tracked-and-chased-through-hyperspace) asks about tracking ships through hyperspace in general. My question is whether Vader had specific knowledge about the destination of the *Tantive IV*. I'm assuming that ships can **not** be tracked after they jump, otherwise the Imperial Fleet would have found the rebel base before Episode 4.

Comment: Yepp it is answered in that question already imho.

Comment: I think he had a general idea of where the ship was heading to. As soon as it left hyperspace, imperial ships found it and alerted Vader of its location.

Comment: @TimSparrow Do you have any sources which say imperial ships notified Vader of its location? If you do, please write up an answer based on those sources. :-)

Comment: @RichS, no, that is my guess. Haven't read Rogue One books yet. It is just a possibility.

Comment: Why should this be re-opened? I see no change made or argument that it's not answered by the other question's answers?

Comment: This is still a duplicate of the other post and should not be re-opened. I'm sorry, but the other answer clearly covers any reason there may be that Vader knew where the ship was going.