# Can the Empire track their own ships?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, hyperspace

The Galactic Empire (*Star Wars*) has tracked the rebels some times using the exit vector of their ships jumping into hyperspace.

But was the Empire able to track their own ships location for example if the ship was stolen? Would they be able to know the exact position of their ship even in hyperspace?

Is there some kind of device installed in the Empire's ships that allows them to track it or could they find out the exact location of the ship in another way?

Comment: With installing a deep space tracker, yes.

Comment: Do you mean something like a homing beacon? That's not what I meant. I was talking about something that is preinstalled in the Empires ships. Is the Empire able to track **any** Stardestroyer (or another ship class) without putting some extra device on it? Do they always know where their own ships are?

Comment: I guest, the Empire can pre-install homing beacons. If they want to.

Comment: Of course, they **can** but **do they actually install this on each of their ships** or on each ship of a certain class? Could they only do it theoretically or is there such a device on every ship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In *Star Wars Rebels* we see one of the rebels disabling an Imperial tracking beacon in a stolen TIE (I'm not sure which TIE it was). They definitely have them on ISDs and bigger ships.

Edit- I believe it is Season 1 Episode 4

Comment: Could you [edit] to include the episode and maybe a video clip if available to provide evidence for this?

Answer (score 2):

***One way to track ships is using:***
*Imperial XX-23 S-Thread Tracker*

> The XX-23 S-Thread tracker was a model of homing beacon used by the Galactic Empire. When the Millennium Falcon escaped from the Death Star, carrying Leia Organa and the battle station's plans to the Rebel base on Yavin 4, the Empire tracked the ship via one such device attached to the freighter's underside. <sub>[[wookieepedia]](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/XX-23_S-thread_tracker)</sub>

Trackers seems to be pre-installed on bigger ships and *The Slave I* and *TIE Advanced* ships can fire homing beacons on to enemy starships with projectile launchers.

***Otherway:***
*If they have an exit vector*

> In ESB, after the Falcon disappears, Vader commands Admiral Piett to:
>
> > Calculate every possible destination along their last know trajectory
>
> Vader clearly cares about what their last trajectory is as well and believes he can find possible destinations from that information.
>
> > If ships can be tracked through hyperspace, why do the Imperials need to place a tracking device on the Falcon?
>
> Imagine that Leia had been smart enough to tell Han "hey by the way they probably will try to track us, maybe we should make some decoy jumps/stops first?"
>
> Suddenly, any visual track through hyperspace becomes worthless. <sub>[[SF StackExchange]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149815/149819)</sub>

Or they just know where ship is going.